# Значение слова "политота"

Tags: лексикон

Я стал встречать по-видимому новое слово *политота*.

Когда я попросил объяснить мне его значение, мне его объяснили так:

> Это школота, только в политике.

Это пролило некоторый свет на то, что оно значит, но полного понимания не дало.

Что обозначает это слово? Можете привести какие-то примеры его использования, которые хорошо иллюстрируют его смысл?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, adding *-та* to the end of a word root creates a word to describe, in a slightly (or not slightly) colloquial or even derogatory way a person or his state/actions represented by that root word.  From [a post here](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9C%D0%A2%D0%90#.D0.A7.D0.A2.D0.9E-.D0.A2.D0.9E.2B.D0.A2.D0.90):

> Например, добрый, улыбающийся Номад — ДОБРОТА. Обдолбанный Номад —
>   НАРКОТА. Номад в кепке и с фингалом под глазом — ГОПОТА. Умный, за
>   размышлением — МУДРОТА, с лопатой — ЛОПАТА, насытившийся после пищи —
>   ВКУСНОТА, после встречи с Петросяном — СМЕХОТА. И так далее.

As for the specific word *политота*, in the same way, it refers in a somewhat derogatory way to politicians and their meanderings that most regular people consider not much more than blabber or even worse.  Additionally, the word may refer to a collection of other things containing references to such political "stuff".

Incidentally, @Anixx refers to the same post as I did in my answer, although I started writing my answer before he posted his.

Answer (score 9):

Произошло от слова "хуита", которое использовал один известный обозреватель компьютерных игр к играм, которые ему не нравились (почти все) и так часто, что слово стало узнаваемым. [Подробности.](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0)

"Политота" означает некий материал, который содержит политическое содержание или мнение, причем слово передает негативный смысл (как бы говоря, что тому, что использует это слово политика вообще не интересна).

Comment: То есть "политота" - это не люди, а материалы, статьи?

Comment: Да, некоторые материалы, содержащие политику, что делает данные материалы скучными и неинтересными.

Comment: Политота – интернет-сленг; вульгарное наименование любого обсуждения или статей на политическую тему. Употребляется в неформальной обстановке.

Answer (score 2):

Политота means politicians in negative form, or people who like to discuss politics.
Note that this word is rarely used, if ever, it is neologism and maybe ruled out as rude by many.

Answer (score 2):

The suffix *-та* forms many derivations in standard Russian: a quick search brings up *высота, доброта, духота, кислота, краснота, красота, нагота, нищета, простота, полнота, прямота, пустота, сирота, слепота, суета, темнота, теснота, тошнота, частота, чистота,* and some others from less standard strata of the language.

Since this suffix, originally from Church Slavonic, is not generally productive in modern Russian, new derivations using it have a distinctive non-standard, ironic ring to them. Many of these predate the Nomad example; e.g *лимита* and *наркота* are from the second half of the last century. *Скукота* and *сволота* are, similarly, rather old, emphatically informal derivations. A comparable example in English would be using the (semantically very similar) suffix *-th* (as in *length, warmth, mirth*) to coin words such as *coolth* or *yumth* for "coolness" and "yumminess".

As @Aleks-G explains, the modern "viral" wave of *-та*-derivations is from Nomad's reviews and his many imitators. *Школота* and *политота* both belong to this new wave -- not derived from one another, but instead sharing the pattern for a non-standard, ironic derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по употреблению, это понятие может подразумевать как группу людей, так и некоторые материалы. "Ай, да ну всю эту политоту", — подразумевает, что человеку надоело читать/обсуждать некие некомпетентные рассуждения о политике, либо притягивание политики в обсуждение вопросов, близкого к ней отношения не имеющих. 
Для группы людей по имени "политота" я бы привел синоним "политически озабоченные" :)